# How to make regular tables in VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

so I am having this problem. I want to create a table in Word using VBA , but every time I do it creates a table with this weird grey border; I want it to look like a normal table. Here is my code I am using

```
    Sub MakeATable()
    Dim actdoc As Document
    Dim newtbl As Table
    Set actdoc = ActiveDocument
    Set myrange = actdoc.Range(0, 0)
    Set newtbl = actdoc.Tables.Add(myrange, 10, 2, wdWord9Behavior)
    End Sub
```

I tired adding in the following to get the table to be a normal style but adding it did not work either

```
   newtbl.Style = Normal
```

What is so weird is that I get no problem at all with the following code

```
   Sub MakeATable()
   Dim actdoc As Document
   Dim newtbl As Table
   Set actdoc = ActiveDocument
   Set myrange = actdoc.Range(0, 0)
   actdoc.Tables.Add Range:=myrange, NumRows:=10, NumColumns:=2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior
```

Can anyone please help me or at least explain what is going on?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first listing, replace

```
wdWord9Behavior
```

with

```
wdWord9TableBehavior
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!
I would give you an upvote, but it seems that my score is not high enough to do so